# iOS automatic App Launch via trigger from locked device

Tags: ios, lockscreen

is it possible to start a app on iOS with an external trigger? E.g. when BLE beacon is detected, WIFI connection is established or NFC tag detected?
I want to auto start the app without the needs of manually setting up routines like in IFTTT.

Is there also a list all with possible triggers for starting an app in iOS?

I'm looking forward for your reply.
Tom

Comment: try silent push notification may be it work :)

Comment: @iOSTeam do you have experience with that? 
I also would like then the app to start even if the phone is locked. Is that possible? I imagine sth like the camera app when you slide from right to left on your lock screen and then the camera is coming up. But other apps/ previous content cannot be accessed - is something similar doable with a app?